# How to speed up iteration through nested lists?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, nested-lists

I have two lists, each with a total of 100,000 lines with words - nested lists. I want to add some strings to a new dictionary by certain condition.

Due to the large number of rows in the lists, iterating through nested lists is very slow. I tried to rewrite my script through a generator, wrote it down through a map(), tried to use a multiprocessing pool - but the speed of program execution did not fundamentally change.

1. How can I improve my code so that the program runs faster?
2. Why was the multiprocessing pool inefficient (slow) when executing this program?

```
list1 = [[['london is capital of uk'],['ny is city in usa'],[...]],[[...],[...],[...]]]
list2 = [[['word1 word2 word3'],[...],[...]],[[...],[...],[...]]] 

def comparing (list1, list2):
    for orig_index_line1, orig_line1 in enumerate(list1):
        for orig_index_line2, orig_line2 in enumerate(list2):
            for new_line1 in list1[orig_index_line1]:
                for new_line2 in list2[orig_index_line2]:
                    if myfunc_compare(new_line1, new_line2) == 1
                        new_dict.append(original_list1[orig_index_line1])
                        break
```

Comment: IMO your code is overcomplicated. Get rid of unused variables, try `itertools.product`, check whether the algorithm is okay (you may be appending the same data several times, when exactly you wanna break?).

Comment: Have you done the math on this?  Just your outer two loops will run 10 BILLION times.  No matter how much optimization you do, doing anything 10,000,000,000 times is going to take a lot of time.  Multiprocessing doesn't help because your data is so large.  Each process has to reinitialize all that.  Fundamentally, you need a different design.